# Missing data in the Discover tab of kibana 6.2.2

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index with 3 documents in it. Each of the documents is very similar--they have the same fields and very close time stamps. When looking at the data in the Discover tab--with no filters and an empty search field--Kibana shows that there are 3 hits (correct), shows 3 buckets each with a count of 1 (correct), but only shows 2 of the documents. This happens regardless of the time range selected (last 5 years, last 24 hours, specific start/end time).

[image]

The data table for the index shows the correct answers.

[image]

The request issued looks correct, and running it in the Dev Tools tab returns the expected 3 documents.  Comparing the Response in the Dev Tools tab shows that it is the same as the one in the Discover tab.

```html
{
  "version": true,
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "endTimeMillis": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "startTimeMillis",
        "interval": "1M",
        "time_zone": "America/Chicago",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "script_fields": {},
  "docvalue_fields": [
    "@timestamp",
    "endTimeMillis",
    "stages.endTimeMillis",
    "stages.startTimeMillis",
    "startTimeMillis"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "startTimeMillis": {
              "gte": 1366809777917,
              "lte": 1524576177917,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "fragment_size": 2147483647
  }
}
```

This is Kibana 6.2.2 running on Ubuntu, and the web browser is Chrome 66. With other indices, I find that between 5% and 30% of the documents I should see are not available for inspection. Has anyone verified this on large datasets? What is happening?

Comment: Can you also copy/paste the request being made (link just to the right of the Table one)?

Comment: Edited the original post to include the request and response.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We want to look into it internally and you can follow along [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/17854)